# Quotienting disk inside sphere result in sphere

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $S^k$ be a topological $k$-dimensional sphere. Let $D^k$ be a $k$ dimensional disk that includes in $S^k$. Let 
$q: D^k \to D^r$ be a map and $r \leq k$. Let
$$W = S^k \sqcup D^r/\sim$$
where  $S^k \supset D^k \ni x \sim q(x)$ is the equivalence relation (one can also express $W$ it as pushout of the inclusion map and $q$).

$Q:$ Under what conditions on $q$, the space $W$ is homeomorphic to $S^k$?

Edit: All the disks mentioned above are closed disk.

One of the conditions that I think of is if $q^{-1}(pt)$ is contractible for every $pt \in D^r$. Is this a sufficient condition?

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the following one: for which q, W is a k-manifold, and then you conclude by left properness and rigidity of the k-spheres.

Comment: @Fedotov If you don't mind, can you please expand on the idea? I did not follow the conclusion part.

Comment: Since the category of topological space is left proper, the map $f:S^{k}\rightarrow W$ is a weak equivalence. If $W$ is a manifold then by generalized poincare (conjecture, now a theorem) $W$ is homeomorphic to $S^{k}$. So you need to find under which condition on $q$, $W$ is a  manifold (actually compact).

Comment: So where is it proved that pushouts of weak equivalences are weak equivalences?

Comment: Push-out of a weak equivalence along a cofibration is a weak equivalence in a left proper model category (you can take it as a definition of left properness).

Comment: Well, then where is it proved that topological spaces form a left proper model category? Somewhere one has to prove something topologically, it can not all just be a game of defining and reformulating :-)

Comment: user39082. If I remember, you can find this result in Hirschhorn book about localizations for example ...

Comment: You might try looking at Kwun, Kyung Whan, 
'Upper semicontinuous decompositions of the n-sphere'
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 13 1962 284–290.